# shader.hlsl file causes error?

Tags: c++, hlsl, shader, directx-11

I'm working on trying to get this DirectX11 proj to load a triangle on the screen that uses a shader.hlsl file to color the triangle based on the positions within the triangle (it is a multi colored triangle that blends together). I am not getting a normal output error either this time. Not sure how to approach/handle this one.

//function that invokes the shaders.hlsl file

```
void InitPipeline()
```

{

```
// load and compile the two shaders

ID3D10Blob *VS, *PS;
D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

// encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

// set the shader objects
devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

// create the input layout object
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
};

dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
```

}

```
struct VOut { 
    float4 position : SV_POSITION; 
    float4 color : COLOR; 
}; 

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) { 
    VOut output; 
    output.position = position; 
    output.color = color; 
    return output; 
} 

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET {
    return color; 
}
```

Comment: Unless you post some code it will be impossible for us to help you.

Comment: this is the code for the shader file but I'm not sure what else to include so that everyone can effectively understand what else is going on.

Comment: @NicholasVaughn Please next time add the code to your question. I have done so for you now. And if you get strange output, it is normally in your best interest to show or explain what the output is you get and how it differs from what you would like/expect to see.

Comment: @NicholasVaughn Please edit your question to include code. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: @Bart I dont know if this is everything you need.

Comment: Do you know if the error comes from the application code or from the shader? And please tell what you mean bu error... nothing is rendered? the application crashes? Have you enabled the debug layer? If so, any errors/warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio? Right click **shaders.hlsl**, find the complete path, and replace **shaders.hlsl** in your `D3DX11CompileFromFile` functions with the absolute path. Make sure to replace `\` characters with `\\` for it to be escaped properly.

Visual Studio leaves the **shaders.hlsl** in the same location as the source code which means that your program can't find it. Is the blue window still displaying? That's the issue I was having.